# Removing last character in ACCESS if it is "."

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write an update query that will remove the last character if it is a period ("."). In EXCEL, I would use the following statement:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=".",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

How can I modify this for ACCESS? I found the following statement in a forum, but ACCESS seems to have a problem with "Substring" and won't let me run the query.

```
 UPDATE table SET field = SUBSTRING(field, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(field) - 1)WHERE field LIKE '%.'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a substring that was one character shorter than your existing string if it ended with a period via the [`LEFT()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/left.php) function :

```
UPDATE YourTable
   SET YourColumn = LEFT(YourColumn, LEN(YourColumn - 1))
 WHERE YourColumn LIKE '*.'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the right way to do this in Access is:

```
UPDATE table
    SET field = LEFT(field, LEN(field) - 1)
    WHERE field LIKE '*.' ;
```

Note that the `like` wildcards are different in MS Access.

Comment: Access tells me "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'LEFT(field, 1, LEN(field) - 1'.

Comment: If OP uses the `ALIKE` operator for ANSI Like, the familiar `%` instead of `*` can be used.